# UWP TreeView ItemTemplateSelector not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, treeview, datatemplateselector

The WPF version of this question is [here:](http://WPF%20TreeView%20ItemTemplateSelector%20not%20working) But it hasn't been answered and I don't know if the UWP TreeView will have the same answer.

I'm trying to add a DataTemplateSelector to the new UWP TreeViews that were just added to windows 10 version 1803 but it isn't working. It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) how to use the XAML TreeView Control and even shows how to modify the template to change the Item Datatemplate which works fine. I need to use a datatemplate selector since each of my nodes is using different objects and I need them displayed differently. The TreeView.Node.Content is being set just fine and everything works except it is passing null over to the datatemplateselector in the Object parameter.

Here is my code: (same as the example from Microsoft just with using ItemTemplateSelector)

```
<Style TargetType="TreeView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                    <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl"
                                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardSelector}"
                                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
                                      CanDragItems="True"
                                      AllowDrop="True"
                                      CanReorderItems="True">
                        <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection>
                                <ContentThemeTransition />
                                <ReorderThemeTransition />
                                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                            </TransitionCollection>
                        </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    </TreeViewList>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Does anyone have any insight or experience on this? My datatemplateselector "CardSelector" works fine and I have been using it in several places without any trouble.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? Then, I could help you diagnose this issue on my side.

Comment: Look at the link I posted in the original question, there is a full example from Microsoft there. As I stated in the question the only line I changed was to use a DataTemplateSelector instead of a single Datatemplate. Based on their example see if you can use a datatemplateselector. The specific example for changing the template is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It seemed that this link is broken, I could not open it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view

Comment: I want to see the `CardSelector` class and the two DataTemplates.

Comment: So the point of my question isn't to get anything that I have working but to see if the TreeViewControl works with a DataTemplateSelector. I only have "CardTemplateSelector" in there because I use it in several other places of my app and I know it works. My question is really a "yes, treeview works with a selector" or "no it doesn't" I'm really looking for someone else to try it with their own test template selector and to let me know if they can get it working. Any specific code from me is not relevant to the question. Just see if you can get it to work with whatever selector you want

Answer (score 1):

> So the point of my question isn't to get anything that I have working but to see if the TreeViewControl works with a DataTemplateSelector. I only have "CardTemplateSelector" in there because I use it in several other places of my app and I know it works. My question is really a "yes, treeview works with a selector" or "no it doesn't" I'm really looking for someone else to try it with their own test template selector and to let me know if they can get it working. Any specific code from me is not relevant to the question. Just see if you can get it to work with whatever selector you want

Yes. The TreeView work well with `ItemTemplateSelector`.

I used the all code in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#code-examples) and create a custom class like the following:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I made another DataTemplate like this:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewObjDataTemplate">
        <Grid Height="44">
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Content.Name}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

My `CardTemplateSelector` class is the following:

```cs
public class CardTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TreeViewItemDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TreeViewObjDataTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        TreeViewNode treeViewNode = item as TreeViewNode;
        if (treeViewNode.Content is StorageFolder|| treeViewNode.Content is StorageFile)
        {
            return TreeViewItemDataTemplate;
        }
        if (treeViewNode.Content is Test)
        {
            return TreeViewObjDataTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return SelectTemplateCore(item);
    }
}
```

I just add the new lines code in `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```cs
TreeViewNode objnode = new TreeViewNode();
Test test = new Test() {Name="Parent"};
objnode.Content = test;
objnode.IsExpanded = true;
objnode.HasUnrealizedChildren = true;
sampleTreeView.RootNodes.Add(objnode);
```

The following is the whole xaml page resource code:

```xml
    <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemDataTemplate">
        <Grid Height="44">
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Content.DisplayName}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewObjDataTemplate">
        <Grid Height="44">
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Content.Name}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:CardTemplateSelector x:Name="CardTemplateSelector" TreeViewItemDataTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDataTemplate}" TreeViewObjDataTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewObjDataTemplate}"></local:CardTemplateSelector>
    
    <Style TargetType="TreeView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                    <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl"
                                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}"
                                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
                                  CanDragItems="True"
                                  AllowDrop="True"
                                  CanReorderItems="True">
                        <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <TransitionCollection>
                                <ContentThemeTransition />
                                <ReorderThemeTransition />
                                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                            </TransitionCollection>
                        </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    </TreeViewList>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing something that I can study but there is no such thing as a bad question.

Comment: I do appreciate your help. I tried this a dozen different ways and couldn't get it to work, so why would I post non-working code done a dozen different ways when all I needed was someone to post one way that works? That isn't logical

Comment: @beatnikthedan It's ok. Have you tried my code sample? It worked well on my side.

Comment: Sorry, not yet... Got pulled onto another thing. I'll try it very soon and let you know but if you say it's all good then I'm sure it will work

Comment: No it isn't working for me... Same issue as I noted in the original question. "protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)" the method is triggering but "object item" is being passed a null value. It happens when I try to use a template selector with a ContentPresenter control too. I use template selectors all the time. but both these controls are passing a null over to the item no clue why. Don't know if it's a problem with my IDE environment or not...

Comment: @beatnikthedan I suggested that you could try to create a new blank UWP project and copy all my code to test on your side. If it worked, then you will know the issue is in your own code, else it maybe your IDE environment or other things.

Comment: Sorry took so long to replay, this all got backlogged for me. I'm pretty sure I found the problem. In all my datatemplateselectors I use the second overload with two parameters. With the Treeview the object is always passed as Null. Using the first method in the templateselector class that only has one parameter seems to work fine. So for whatever reason with a treeview template selector you can't use the second overload in the template selector class. Thanks for your help, I figured it out by looking at your example.

Comment: I think it is broken, see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/615

Comment: I can confirm that if you use the wrong override in the template selector, it won't work. Don't use `protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)` but use `protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be confusion about where to apply the DataTemplate. And the all important TargetType is ignored.

If you want a handle on the data item in your custom DataTemplateSelector, you need to:

**OPTION 1**

- Apply the DataTemplateSelector on TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector
- Make sure that the DataTemplates have **TreeViewNode** as the target type.

Only then the data item of the TreeViewNode is supplied to the SetTemplateCore(object item) and SetTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container) overrides of your custom DataTemplateSelector.
A working example is found here: [Pictures and Music library tree view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tree-view#pictures-and-music-library-tree-view)

**OPTION 2**

- Apply the DataTemplateSelector on TreeViewItem.ContentTemplateSelector
- Make sure that the DataTemplates have **[YOUR-DATA-TYPE]** as the target type
- In the TreeView.ItemTemplate bind the DataContext AND Content property to [YOUR-DATA-TYPE], i.e.

```xml
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="[YOUR-DATA-TYPE]">
        <TreeViewItem DataContext="{Binding}" ... Content="{Binding}">
            <TreeViewItem.ContentTemplateSelector>
                <YourDataTemplateSelector.TemplateA>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="[YOUR-DATA-TYPE]">
                        ...
```

```c#
// YourDataTemplateSelector
protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null) return null;
        return (([YOUR-DATA-TYPE])item).IsSomething ? TemplateA : TemplateB;
    }
```