# WinUI 3 DataTemplateSelector in ContentControl doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I want to implement a page, which will render the page depending on the state of its view model. I tried to add some breakpoint in the template selector when debug, I found it never been called. The page is blank.

**Xaml**

```xml
<local:DevicesPageTemplateSelector 
            x:Key="devicesPageTemplateSelector" 
            Normal="{StaticResource HasDataTemplate}"
            NoDevice="{StaticResource NoDeviceTemplate}"
            NoRunningServer="{StaticResource NoAdbServerTemplate}" />


<Grid>
        <ContentControl 
            x:Name="content" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource devicesPageTemplateSelector}" 
            DataContext="{x:Bind viewModel}"
            >
        </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

**DataTemplateSelector**

```cs
public class DevicesPageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate Normal { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate NoRunningServer { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate NoDevice { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
        {
            var viewModel = (DevicesViweModel)item;

            if (!viewModel.IsNoRunningServer)
            {
                return NoRunningServer;
            }

            if (viewModel.HasNoDevice)
            {
                return NoDevice;
            }

            return Normal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found that I need to override `protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)` instead of `protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516496/uwp-treeview-itemtemplateselector-not-working/50635546#comment123747125_50635546) it's the other way around. You need to use the other override to get the Template Selector to work.